# Django migration with 2 DBs?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I've the databases `db1` and `db2`. The schemas of both DBs should be created with the same migration script.

The Django docs mention [DATABASE_ROUTERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/) and [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython), but I didn't manage to get it working so far. The function is called, but `migrations.CreateModel()` has no impact when called from the function: the table is not created.

Migration script:

```
# 0001_initial.py

def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    if schema_editor.connection.alias == 'db1':
        print('This line is called!')
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                # ...
            ]
        )

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True
    
    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards, hints={'target_db': 'db1'}),
    ]
```

Router:

```
DatabaseRouter:
    # ...
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if 'target_db' in hints:
            return db == hints['target_db']
        return True
```

Command:

```
python manage.py migrate --database=db1
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you simply write the `migrations.CreateModel` in the `operations` list? In fact why are you even writing the migration for making a model manually?? Just write the code for the model in `models.py` and run `makemigrations` and you will automatically get a migration file for that...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I need to define somewhere which model is created in which DB which is not done by `makemigrations`. How would you do that?

Comment: That is to be done in the _router_ in the `allow_migrate` method of course. You will check the `app_label` passed and the database alias `db` and return `True` in case it should be migrated there, `False` if not and `None` if the other routers should decide.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Do you have a working answer that I could use and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`migrations.CreateModel` does not create a model in the database upon instantiation. It is supposed to be present in the `operations` list where the migrations system will then use it to create the model. Furthermore you shouldn't be writing this migration manually anyway! Just write the code for the model in `models.py`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Your fields, etc.
```

Next since your question asks how to control which model is migrated to which database. These tasks are supposed to be done in the [Database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers), particularly in the `allow_migrate` method. You can check the values passed for `db`, `app_label`, and `model_name` return whether the model should be migrated there. For example:

```
class MyRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        ...

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        ...

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        ...

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        # Suppose I want to migrate all models from the app 'some_app' to 'db1' only.
        if app_label in ['some_app']:
            return db == 'db1'
        # Suppose I want to migrate 'MyModel' to 'db2' only.
        if model_name == 'mymodel':  # 'mymodel' is lowercase 'MyModel'
            return db == 'db2'
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I was looking for.